# Como hago una suma de todas las casillas de una matriz? c++

Tags: c++, matrices

estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual almaceno en una matriz las ventas de los productos de un numero x de vendedores, al finalizar tengo que mostrar la suma de las ventas totales de cada vendedor (individual), y luego mostrar la suma de todas las ventas (global), ya logre realizar la suma de las ventas de cada vendedor, de forma que el programa me muestra

"suma de las ventas del vendedor 1: 2000 (por ejemplo)

suma de las ventas del vendedor 2: 3000 (por ejemplo "

pero no se como realizar una suma de todos los valores de las casillas para que me de el total de las ventas globales

Aqui el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int matriz [18][10];
    int sumafila;

    for (int i=0; i<18; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            cout << "Digite ingresos del producto " << j+1 << " del vendedor " << i+1 << ": ";
            cin >> matriz [i][j];

        }
    }

    cout<<endl;

    for (int i=0; i<18 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            cout << matriz [i][j]<<"    ";

        }

        cout<<endl;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<18; i++)
    {
        sumafila = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
         sumafila = sumafila + matriz [i][j];
        }
        cout << "\nLa suma de las ventas del vendedor " << i+1 << " es: " << sumafila;
    }




}
```

Agradeceria su ayuda :D

SOLUCION PROBLEMA:

Para poder realizar la suma de el total, declare una nueva variable llamada

```
int total = 0
```

y luego de esto, en la suma de las filas, agregue una operacion que fuera sumando el total de cada una de estas filas, para obtener el total, de la siguiente manera:

```
total = total + sumafila;
```

con lo que finalmente, el ciclo quedaria asi:

```
 for (int i=0; i<18; i++)
    {
        sumafila = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
         sumafila = sumafila + matriz [i][j];

        }

        cout << "\nLa suma de las ventas del vendedor " << i+1 << " es: " << sumafila;
        total = total + sumafila;
    }
```

Y finalente, muestro el total con un cout;

```
cout << "\nLa suma total de todos los vendedores es: " << total;
```

Comment: Para las ventas globales no seria la suma de los totales de cada vendedor? Si ya lograste sacar los totales individuales, solo ten una variable en la que los vayas sumando

Comment: Si, es lo que estoy pensando, solo que no se como hacerlo, y es en lo que estoy estancado, gracias igualmente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUCION PROBLEMA:

Para poder realizar la suma de el total, declare una nueva variable llamada

```
int total = 0
```

y luego de esto, en la suma de las filas, agregue una operacion que fuera sumando el total de cada una de estas filas, para obtener el total, de la siguiente manera:

```
total = total + sumafila;
```

con lo que finalmente, el ciclo quedaria asi:

```
 for (int i=0; i<18; i++)
    {
        sumafila = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
         sumafila = sumafila + matriz [i][j];

        }

        cout << "\nLa suma de las ventas del vendedor " << i+1 << " es: " << sumafila;
        total = total + sumafila;
    }
```

Y finalente, muestro el total con un cout;

```
cout << "\nLa suma total de todos los vendedores es: " << total;
```

Comment: Marca tu respuesta como la correcta para que pueda ayudarle a futuras personas a encontrar la solucion mas rapida :)

Answer (score 0):

Con una matriz con la que muestras, de tamaño fijo, puedes recorrer cada fila con un `for` de rango y después usar la función [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) de la cabecera [`<numeric>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric):

```
int matriz [18][10];

for (const auto &fila : matriz)
    std::cout << "Suma: " << std::accumulate(std::begin(fila), std::end(fila), 0) << '\n';
```

El primer parámetro indica dónde empezar a sumar  (el principio de la fila, indicado por `std::begin`) el segundo indica dónde acabar de sumar (el final de la fila, indicado por `std::end`) y el tercer parámetro es el valor inicial de la suma, que en este caso obviamente debe ser cero.